# how to set image picker image chosen for button in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to set a `UIButton` image with the image chosen from an image picker.  My code looks like this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    UIImage *editedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];


    // Resize image
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(478, 640));
    [editedImage drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 478, 640)];
    UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [self.cameraButton setImage:smallImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

When this code executes it removes the original image I had set and shows nothing.  If I click the space where the image button was, it still kicks off the `IBAction`, but no image.

I have connected the `IBOoutlet` so it is not that.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you editing image on uiimagepickercontroller after you take the picture?

Comment: @kkocabiyik I'm only doing what I am in the code above. So I believe the answer is yes.  Even if I remove the resize I get the same results.

Comment: Have u debugged it? I think the editedImage is coming null right?

Answer (score 1):

whoops, `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` should be `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`

Comment: That's what i was saying! :)